# Vim+Tmux unfocus airline when switching away

Tags: vimrc, plugin-airline, tmux

I'm using Vim with tmux and I wanted to know if there was a signal or something to 'deactivate' the vim window (like when you switch between vim windows) but also when you switch between Vim and Tmux. I'm using vim-tmux-navigator and tried to modify it to have this effect.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you clarify your terms? What does « deactivate » mean? And when you say « window » (twice), are you referring to vim split windows, tmux windows (sub-parts of tmux sessions, similar to vim tabpages), or tmux panes (sub-parts of tmux windows, similar to vim split windows)? It’s also not precisely clear what you mean by signal, but I suppose that’s because that’s the question.

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/1807

Comment: https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/1807 Is exactly what I meant, thank you for the link

Comment: I tried to use 'airline_focuslost_inactive' parameter to 1 but it doesn't do anything, also tried looking on the github page and people have other problems with it

Comment: @ndfg201 you did not specify what exactly you want (or I did not understand it). But I know of no problems with the given airline parameters. So please be precise (and open an new issue if you think you have found a bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that work
in tmux.conf :

```
set -g focus-events on
```

Nothing more

Comment: Your answer was automatically flagged as low quality because it is very short. I'm declining the flag, but we encourage answers to include details that explain how they resolve the issue! You can [edit] to add more information, if you choose.

Answer (score 0):

[vim-tmux-focus-events](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events) will send FocusGained and FocusLost events to vim.

This will enable Vim to reload a file that has changed on disk once you switch back to the Vim window.

I don't know airline but if it uses the same events it will work there as well.